# Why does ASP.NET_SessionID change when i open the PRINT Dialog in IE and Edge?

Tags: asp.net

We have an ASP.NET web application. After successfully logging in to the application, i want to print the page for some reason.I try with ctrl+p. After printing , if i try to click on the page it redirects me to the log in page. We observer that for some reason ASP.NET_SessionId is changed after i pressed crtl+p.
This happens only in IE and EDGE.

Can anyone help us with this one?

Comment: ASP.NET_SessionID is assigned by backend server. Do you see any new request going to server on CTRL+P ?

Comment: I see a new request is sent for styles, probably to get any special styles for `print media`.

Comment: Yes i see the request is sent. One strange thing is when i log in to the server where the application is hosted and then try to do the same operation in IE, it works just fine.

Comment: Check your cache settings in IE. Have you disabled caching ?

Comment: Caching is enabled.

Comment: Is you application live? Can I see it over the internet ?